# How can I change the TcpInitialRTT in Windows 10?

Tags: tcp, windows-10

I saw [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/193160/which-is-the-default-tcp-connect-timeout-in-windows) but I can't find this parameter in the registry in windows 10 and also google doesn't turn up much, just one forum where it is claimed that the parameter no more exists. How can I change the tcp rtt in windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried creating the entry? Lots of registry settings are not there by default.

Comment: Not really, but I guess Windows has to have a default saved somewhere, maybe they just renamed or moved that registry entry? Not sure

Comment: You should try to create it and see if it works as intended. A lot of Registry entries aren't there by default, and their "default" is taken directly from the program and/or system itself. But if you create the Registry key/entry, then the program/system will check if it exists and if it is and it's valid, it'll take precedence over the default.